# Blender keeps crashing while rendering a cloth simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm trying to render a cached cloth simulation in eevee but blender keeps crashing at different points during the render. There are no other visible objects in the scene or subdivisions applied. The cloth simulation plays back fine in the viewport.

My PC specs are a 3090TI + 2080TI + 128GB Ram and a 24 core threadripper. Memory usage is high but doesn't seem to be spiking.

I've cached the simulation to an Nvme M.2 drive.

I'm at a loss as to how to resolve this. Can anybody help me troubleshoot?

Comment: Man, I have the same problem. I now realized that I added a subdive modifier to the fabric in 1pont to viewport and 2 point to render, but I cached the simulation in 1 iteration of the subdive. understand? and in the render I have 2 iterations. I hope it helped you